# Postincrement and preincrement in Java expressions

Tags: java, expression, variable-assignment, increment

> What does each expression evaluate to? Assume x is 2 before each one.

- `int num = x++ * 3;`
  So this would be equivalent to (2)*3 or num=6 and x is now 3.
- `num *= x;`
  num =2*2 or 4
- `(x < 2) && (x > 1)`
  Becomes FALSE, because (2<2)=false and (2>1)=true so it's false.
- `(++x < 2) || (x < 1)`
  `(3<2)` is false and then `((2+1)<1)` is also false, so it's false?
  One question is in this case, is the preincrement applied to the variable before the break? Should the second x value be 3 or 2?
  I also have the same question for postincrement. Let's say I have `num=x++ *x++` where initial x=2. So is this 2*2 or 2*3?

Comment: Which "break" are you talking about?

Comment: On the fourth one. Since the preincrement is in the first bracket thing (im sure it has a special name) does it effect the value of the x in the second parenthesis comparison?

Comment: Like if the value of x is pre/post incremented in a first half of an AND or OR statement, does it affect the value of the second half's value?

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself? --> [Ideone](http://ideone.com)

Comment: This question might help: [Pre & post increment operator behavior in C, C++, Java, & C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457130/pre-post-increment-operator-behavior-in-c-c-java-c-sharp).

Comment: I don't have admin rights to install Eclipse nor the SDK, but thanks to JRL I can do my Java testing now. Really cool program!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incremented before the "break" yes. Basically it's the first thing java does (parenthesis are still the first ones actually). So in (++x < 2) || (++x < 3) the 2nd ++x happens after the first one if it isn't true.

Comment: I realize it adds one to the value of the x for the first half before executing the statement. Let me try to explain this a different way:
`var x=2;`<br>
`(x++ < 4)&&(x==2);`<br>
Is the second statement true or false. I am wondering whether preincrement affects the entire line's x value..

Comment: @Chris: Why don't you just run it? If the result is `false`, the second statement is `false`. If it is `true`, it's `true`. That's easy to find out.

Comment: @Felix Kling: I don't have admin rights to the comptuer I am on to install either Eclipse or the SDK. Although someone posted this cool online java runner thing I am using now. I've never done it before, so how can you return the value of the OR statement without writing a large if else thing?

Comment: @fbernardo if the program gives me this error: "cannot return a value from method whose result type is void" that means the statement is false right? Or does it mean something is actually wrong?

Comment: If you declare a void method (like main) you can't return a value. That's what a void method is, a method that doesn't return anything... So, that doesn't mean it's true or false.

Comment: Btw, if you want to return the result of a boolean expression like "a | b" the return type is "boolean".

Answer (score 1):

`int num = x++ * 3;` => OK: x = 3, num = 6
`num *= x;` => what's the initial value of num ? if num = 2, then you are also OK.
`(x < 2) && (x > 1)` is false when x = 2, OK
`(++x < 2) || (x < 1)` is false when x = 2, OK as well

I remember I had a look at the openJDK, especially the `Lower` class in javac source and ++x is translated into x += 1 therefore you can see it as:
`((x += 1)) < 2)` which is (whithout type casting): `((x = (x + 1)) < 2)`. The second test will have the newer x value i.e 3 because java evaluates the conditions from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes those are some very basic concepts, do yourself a favour.  Download unittest framework something like jUnit would do.  Then you can run all these tests quickly with a few asserts that will show you exactly what is going on.  Another way to do it without much overhead is just to print it out on the console.

```
int num = x++ * 3;
System.out.println( "num=" + num );  // num=6
```

Comment: I don't have admin rights to the comptuer I am on to install either Eclipse or the SDK. Although someone posted this cool online java runner thing I am using now.

Answer (score 0):

```
num *= x;
num =2*2 or 4
```

I don't know where you got that.

`num *= x;` is equivalent to `num = num * x;`.  If num was 6 (from the previous statement) then it would now be 12 (assuming x is still 2).

Comment: in this case, x becomes 3 after the first sum, so num will be 18.

Comment: Thats what She gave me. I think shes assuming that all of the programs are separate with the x value initialized at 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Assume `x` is 2 before each one." Is that a given assumption or is it an assumption you're making? I don't believe that you can make that assumption. I believe that you have evaluate all of these statements in sequence.
2. What is the expanded form of `a *= b`?
3. What is the initial value of `num` when you're at the second statement?
4. On your last statement you did correctly (assuming your initial conditions are correct) compute `(2+1) < 1` because `x` has been incremented.

Keep track of the values of `x` and `num` after each statement and I think you'll get to the right answer.

Good luck!