# Groovy removing extra empty lines in StringBuilder Object

Tags: regex, groovy, stringbuilder

Trying to remove any extra empty lines beyond 2 empty lines in a file made from a StringBuilder. The code is in groovy so I seem to not understand why simple java procedure don't seem to work. Tried 3 things... Any suggestions? See code snippets below

#### Regex doesn't do anything.

```
private static final removeExtraLines1(StringBuilder text)
{
    String twoLines = "MIAW";
    Pattern extraLines = Pattern.compile("\n")
    text.replaceAll(extraLines, twoLines);
}
```

#### My own method that deleteCharAt doesn't work too?

```
private void removeExtraLines(StringBuilder text)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < text.length()-1)
    {
        if(text.charAt(i) == System.lineSeparator() && text.charAt(i++) == System.lineSeparator())
        {
            text.deleteCharAt(i++);
            System.out.println("REPLACED AN EMPTY LINE");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Modifying the toString() method says regex method replaceAll is deprecated.

```
@Override 
String toString()
{
    def padding = " " * (4 * (level - 1) )
    padding + "cat level $level [$title]: " + 
        contained.collect { 
            it.toPaddedString(padding) }

    ////My Code
    String twoLines = System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator();
    Pattern extraLines = Pattern.compile(System.lineSeparator()+ System.lineSeparator()+ System.lineSeparator()+System.lineSeparator()) 
    _toString().replaceAll(extraLines, twoLines)
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Couldn't get to format the coding correctly. It was my first post on here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that each approach has a mistake:

1. `replaceAll()` does not modify the `StringBuilder`. Instead, it returns a new `String`. Also, the regular expression is incorrect.
2. Improper use of the post/pre-increment, as stated by Vijay.
3. OK, I have no idea. I gave up trying to understand the third approach.

The easiest method is to use `replaceAll()` with a proper regular expression, and then use `replace()` to take the output of `replaceAll()` and make it the entire content of the `StringBuilder`:

```
private static final removeExtraLines1(StringBuilder text) {
    text.replace(0, text.size(), builder.replaceAll('\n\n', '\n'))
}
```

Comment: Seems to do something now. The only issue is that my new lines aren't \n depending on the system I am using. Throughout the code we use System.lineSeparator(). So when I used replaceAll with '\n' it doesn't recognize empty line. Quickly removing that for another character present in the file proves that this approach does work. Can I use replaceAll with System.lineSeparator()?

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot about that. Yes, you can use `System.lineSeparator()`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ++i (pre increment) instead of i++ (post increment)

```
       if(text.charAt(i) == System.lineSeparator() && text.charAt(++i) == System.lineSeparator())
        {
            text.deleteCharAt(++i);
            System.out.println("REPLACED AN EMPTY LINE");
        }
```

checkout [Pre & post increment operator behavior in C, C++, Java, & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457130/pre-post-increment-operator-behavior-in-c-c-java-c-sharp)

Comment: I just did. No change to my StringBuilder

Comment: Or, you know, don't use pre and post increment, as SO MANY people use it poorly.