# c++ differencebetween --k[i] and k[i]--

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's say we have afunction like.

```
void f(int *k){
  k++; //increments the pointer to the second element
  (--(*k)); //what exactly does is mean? 

}
int main(){
  v[]={1,2,3};
  f(v); //passes the pointer to the forst elemento of v
}
```

What order does it follow?
And what if I had `--k[1]` in a function like `void f(int k[3])`?

Comment: C++ Operator Precedence: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: If downvoters could explain..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre & post increment operator behavior in C, C++, Java, & C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457130/pre-post-increment-operator-behavior-in-c-c-java-c-sharp)

Comment: @flaviodesousa Not really.

Answer (score 1):

> c++ differencebetween --k[i] and k[i]--

Former does pre-decrement. Latter does post-decrement.

> ```
> (--(*k)); //what exactly does is mean?
> ```

`operator*` is the dereference operator.

> What order does it follow?

All expressions follow the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) rules. Parenthesized groups have tighter binding than any operator.

Answer (score 0):

Best idea would be to open debugger and check step by step:)

When you call function `f(v)` you pass pointer to array - to the first element of it.

Inside of `f(v)` you first increase pointer by 1 (`k++`). What's to note here, it doesn't matter what type of objects you pass, it's always moved to another object, so size of object doesn't matter.

Now `(--(*k))` - you decrement what's inside of `*k` (which now points to the second element of array - so 2).

In conclusion, after you finish function v == { 1, 1, 3};