# Increment in java

Tags: java, increment, post-increment

Can anybody explain it to me why the value of n1 is not increasing by 1 in this case, or in other words why the mathematical operation isn't showing 1.

```
package com.company;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(isNumber(20, 21));
    }
    public static double isNumber (double n1, double n2){

        double calc = n1++ / n2;
        return calc;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the post-increment operator, which increases the value after returning the result. `++n1` would return an incremented number in the calculations.

Comment: You have tagged this with [tag:post-increment]… you do understand what the "post" in "post-increment" means as opposed to *pre-increment*…?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre & post increment operator behavior in C, C++, Java, & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457130/pre-post-increment-operator-behavior-in-c-c-java-c-sharp)

Comment: just print n1 before returninc calc an you will see that it really is incremented. However, n1 isn't returned so the change is unnoticed

Comment: i bet you get calc= `20/21`. If yes think about the what the name of that operator  **post**-increment could mean ;)

Comment: @DavideSpataro: I'd rather see that written as `20.0 / 21`, or `20.0 / 21.0`.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right, it makes a hell of a difference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is increased, but after the execution of line double `calc = n1++ / n2;`.

That happens because you used a post increment operator.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isNumber(20, 21));
    }

    public static double isNumber (double n1, double n2){
        double calc = n1++ / n2;
        System.out.println(n1); // Prints 21
        return calc;
    }
}
```

Your code is equivalent to

```
    public static double isNumber (double n1, double n2){

        double calc = n1 / n2;
        n1 = n1 + 1;
        return calc;
    }
```

If you need to apply the increment before the division, you need to apply the preincrement operator as follow:

```
double calc = ++n1 / n2;
```

Using the preincrement operator the code is equivalent to:

```
public static double isNumber (double n1, double n2){
    n1 = n1 + 1;
    double calc = n1 / n2;
    return calc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The result will be a little less than `1`.

`n1++ / n2` is evaluated as `20.0 / 21.0` with the *side-effect* of `n1` being increased by `1`, meaning that `n1` will then be exactly `21.0` as incrementing a floating point `double` by `1` from `20.0` is exact. This will have no effect on the value of `n1` in the caller since parameters are passed *by value* in Java.

Did you want `++n1 / n2`?